# add X-Robots-Tag to apache config

Tags: apache2

I need to fix my server with the robots tags headers,

```
X-Robots-Tag
```

is there an easy way to add this in apache httpd.conf?

Answer (score 7):

This worked well for me:

(insert into /etc/apache2/sites-available/<site name>.conf inside the "VirtualHost" tag)

```
Header Set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive, nosnippet"
```

The "mod_headers" Apache Module must be enabled also:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader append X-Robots-Tag "something here"
</ifModule>
```

You need to have enabled and activated the mod_headers